# How to specify a build agent in vNext build

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I have a vNext build definition, which has a agent pool specified. This agent pool has more then one agent. 
I want to specify say agent number 2 to be used by this build definition. How can I make sure that for a particular build definition a specific build Agent is used to run the build?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a User Capability to that specific build agent then in the build definition you put that capability as a demand (General tab)

Answer (score 2):

Now you can use `Agent.Name` or `Agent.ComputerName` demands in build def or when queuing a build:

Reference: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericparvin/2017/02/08/how-to-send-tfs-build-to-a-specific-agent-or-server/