# Unit tests are failing when run from dotCover

Tags: unit-testing, tfs, tfsbuild, dotcover

I have a TFS 2015 build which builds one of our applications (it's an ASP.NET Web API application). As part of the build process it runs our unit tests.

I have a *Visual Studio Tes*t build step which runs these unit tests and they all pass okay.

I then run **dotCover** from this same build to determine code coverage (no we don't use the built-in code coverage as we don't have enterprise licences). However, when run from **dotCover** all the same unit tests fail.

I use a script step to run a batch file which invokes **dotCover** as follows.

**E:\JetBrains\Installations\dotCover05\dotCover.exe analyse coverage.xml /LogFile=dotcover.log**

The **dotCover** log file doesn't seem to give any indications as to why the unit tests have failed.

Any ideas why the unit tests pass when run from the *Visual Studio Test* build step and then fail when run from **dotCover**?

Comment: Which build system are you using? XAML or vNext? I'd like to reproduce this issue at my side.

Comment: I'm using vNext

Comment: Can not reproduce the issue, can you check the settings in your coverage.xml?

Comment: The settings in my coverage.xml file are used on another build without a problem. It's only this particular build that is causing problems.

Comment: It seems that the problem is related to the fact that that my build uses an XML file to hold certain values. This XML file is found by VSTest when run under TFS but not by dotCover. 

When dotCover runs it creates a TestResults folder which it copies all the necessary files required to run the tests. All files are copied except the XML file.  I have set the file to "Copy to output folder" so can't understand why this file isn't copied. I tried copying the file manually as a batch file but the folder structure is created by dotCover so it doesn't exist until I actually run the code coverage.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the problem is related to the fact that my build uses an XML file to hold certain data values. This XML file is found by VSTest when run under TFS but not by dotCover.

When dotCover runs it creates a *TestResults* folder which it then copies all the necessary files to required to run the unit tests. All files are copied except the XML file. I have set the file to "*Copy always*" so can't understand why this file isn't copied. I tried copying the file manually as a batch file but the folder structure is created by dotCover so it doesn't exist until I actually run the code coverage.

The solution is to decorate my test classes with the **DeploymentItem()** attribute.

```
[TestClass]
[DeploymentItem("File.xml")]
```

This has resolved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your build service account have enough permission to run the dotcove.exe. According to your `E:\JetBrains\Installations\dotCover05\dotCover.exe` Seems you didn't install for ***all users*** on the build agent.  Which should installed under  `%ProgramFiles(x86)%` not %LOCALAPPDATA%\JetBrains\Installations.

[image]

Try to use `CoreInstructionSet` parameter in your dotCover as a workaround  for your situation. Details see below picture.
[image]

After doing this try to run the build again.

[image]

Comment: I installed dotCover on a non-default drive due to limited space on the default drive.

I have tried adding the /CoreInstructionSet=x86 parameter but it hasn't made any difference.

I have another build that uses dotCover as part of the build and it works quite happily, so it seems that dotCover is installed and configured correctly. It is just this particular build where it fails and I can't understand why.

How can I find out what user the build is using to run the builds? What is registry-free dorCover configuration and how do I use it?

Thanks.

Comment: Seems related to your build agent. Are you using different build agent for your two build definitions? You can try to specify a build agent. Follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39341041/how-to-specify-a-build-agent-in-vnext-build/39341669#39341669

Comment: And what's the difference with your two build definitions? Are they in different team project or the same team project?

Comment: We have one build agent that runs on both team projects. Apart from the fact that the builds are building different applications, they are very similar. They both build Visual Studio solutions, run unit tests and run code coverage. What is considered best practice with regards build agents? Should it be one agent per team project?

Comment: No, it's according to your requirements.  As you add more code and people, you'll eventually need more agents. Back to the issue, seems unreasonable. Once you remove dotCover, the unit test pass. Once you add it, the unit test fail. And this work with the same settings on another application. Try to create a new build definition with the same setting and try again. Also double check the difference of your two definitions.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this method if it is failed by the file copying: [Shadow-copying in dotCover: if your NUnit tests fail during continuous testing](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2015/12/28/shadow-copying-in-dotcover-if-your-nunit-tests-fail-during-continuous-testing/) .