# Unit tests failing in xunit.runner.console but passes locally

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, xunit, dotcover

Our TFS CI build uses dotCover for running xUnit tests. However some of the tests are failing there but locally they passes.

I downloaded dotCover.CommandLineTools and xunit.runner.console from nuget. unpacked the packages and tried to locally run `dotCover cover` command as is executed in TFS pipeline:

```
.\tools\dotcover.exe cover /TargetExecutable=".\..\xunit-runner\tools\net461\xunit.console.exe"
/TargetArguments="c:\Projects\MySolution\Sources\MyTestProject\bin\Debug\MyTestProject.dll -xml c:/temp/testResultFile.xml"
/Output="c:/temp/coverageResultFile.dcvr"
/Filters='-:module=xunit.*;-:module=*UnitTests*'
```

Get the same errors as in CI. From my investigation of errors that dotCover output showed in failing tests it seems that mock data are not the same when running tests locally from VS and running them with dotCover.

Does anybody faced such problem? Any solution for it?

**EDIT:** Just tried one more thing, ran command

`.\xunit.console c:\Projects\MySolution\Sources\MyTestProject\bin\Debug\MyTestProject.dll` and found that this gives me same errors as on CI so the cause of problems is not CI, nor dotCover but xunit.runner.console.

Any new points to this?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description and analysis. This issue seems not related to TFS side(such as configuration of build task/pipeline. Since it's the same result when you directly run `dotCover cover` command locally as TFS build server.

Take a look at this similar issue check if it's helpful: [Unit tests are failing when run from dotCover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40082990/unit-tests-are-failing-when-run-from-dotcover)

> It seems that the problem is related to the fact that my build uses an
>   XML file to hold certain data values. This XML file is found by VSTest
>   when run under TFS but not by dotCover.
>
> When dotCover runs it creates a TestResults folder which it then
>   copies all the necessary files to required to run the unit tests. All
>   files are copied except the XML file. I have set the file to "Copy
>   always" so can't understand why this file isn't copied. I tried
>   copying the file manually as a batch file but the folder structure is
>   created by dotCover so it doesn't exist until I actually run the code
>   coverage

Another method if it is failed by the file copying: [Shadow-copying in dotCover: if your NUnit tests fail during continuous testing](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2015/12/28/shadow-copying-in-dotcover-if-your-nunit-tests-fail-during-continuous-testing/) .

Comment: Thanks, I will check it. Please, edit the first link you stated, it refers to this question :)
I think our mocks are imported from jsons so I thought that problem could be in using files. I need to check. I'm quite new to the project, so I'm not so familiar with it yet.

Comment: @Gondil Sorry for the mistyped. Have corrected and updated. Also not familiar with dotcover to me, can't help to dig into the root cause. Only could give some suggestions and directions.

Comment: Thanks, for edit. I understand that you are not familiar with dotCover, me neither :D I'm also just assuming what is wrong with it and that's why I was asking here, more heads, more experiences :) I will try to focus on dotCover and the files used and try to find the solution.

Comment: Other team member helped me.. He created something like kind of lets say Mocking FW so I was little bit lost in it. Don't know to this time (I think my colleague neither) why it wasn't working properly with xunit.runner.console. There was made some kind of general initialization of mocks using C# Attributes and it wasn't working when running through xunit.runner.console. So probably this question could be closed even when it don't have a general solution.