# Is it possible to spread pipeline load between all of the existing agents within the Azure DevOps agent pool?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

We have created our own self hosted agents on an AKS cluster.

We have 3 replicas, using a StatefulSet which mounts a Persistent Volume (PV) in order to use docker's cache. This means that `/var/lib/docker` is a mount on each replica.

Up until everything works fine.

However, it seems like that `agent-0` does most of the work while `agent-1` and `agent-2` are working way less. This causes a problem, as `PV-0` is almost using it's entire capacity and `PV-1` and `PV-2` aren't:

```
agent-0
/dev/sdc                 98.3G     83.8G     14.5G  85% /var/lib/docker
agent-1
/dev/sdd                 98.3G     35.3G     63.0G  36% /var/lib/docker
agent-2 
/dev/sdc                 98.3G      2.1G     96.2G   2% /var/lib/docker
```

Is there a way to control Azure DevOps' pipelines so that the load will be spread between the agents instead of always using `agent-0`?

Comment: interesting concept. how many parallel jobs do you have in the organization?

Comment: @MarioDietner - it depends. It can be more than 4 sometimes, but usually 1-2 jobs are running in parallel. Just to make sure, it's not the parallelism that I'm worried about, but rather what decides which agent is taking the next job

Comment: afaik we cannot control which agent is going to be next from a pool. but we can influence by setting for example agent demands (capabilities). but if you are concerned about even distribution try redesign some pipelines to multi job pipelines to use as little load as possible in one job and if possible use non-dependent jobs. Also make sure you have sufficient parallel jobs for your hosted agents.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT I have replied with the solution that we decided to go with

Answer (score 1):

We have ended up with a different solution, moving from Docker in docker (dind) to Docker outside of docker (DooD).

The main reason that we initially wanted to use our own self hosted agents was the need for docker layer caching, as it takes too much time to build docker images using the hosted agents.

At some point, we figured that we would have to support ARM based images, and start to use [docker buildx](https://docs.docker.com/buildx/working-with-buildx/) which made us use the docker dind solution.

We are aware of the risk that is included by mounting the docker.sock:

> In order to use Docker from within a Docker container, you need to bind-mount the Docker socket. This has very serious security implications - namely, code inside the container can now run as root on your Docker host. If you're sure you want to do this, see the bind mount documentation on Docker.com.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/docker?view=azure-devops#using-docker-within-a-docker-container

But for the time being, this solves our issue as we won't have to manage PVs per pods, but rather use the same docker to build all of our non-ARM images.

A side note: as for ARM, we would still be using a different agent, which will be running docker buildx in order to build docker images.

Answer (score 0):

What you could try is to configure multi-agent for your agent job and type 3 for your 3 agents, if you want to spread the load:

[image]

I also think that it will only consume the amount of agents corresponding to your parallel job count for your organization. As stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#slicing):

> Each agent can run only one job at a time. To run multiple jobs in
>   parallel you must configure multiple agents. You also need sufficient
>   parallel jobs.

**EDIT**

The above suggested method works only with tasks who support [slicing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#slicing). Otherwise it will just parallel the same execution. In case your tasks dont support slicing, but you have independent Tasks in your pipeline, you can split the Agent Job in 2 or more, without setting the Dependency on previous job, and the jobs will run in parallel if you have sufficient parallel jobs.

Comment: we are not using slicing. Most of our jobs are dependent on the success of are unit tests, while most of the unit tests use a Docker image

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to control Azure DevOps' pipelines so that the load will be spread between the agents instead of always using agent-0?

I am afraid there is no such out of box way to control the build/release workloads to be evenly distributed to all agents, if we could not use the feature multi-agent.

**As workaround**, we could clone the our pipeline/job into three, each with different demands. Then set custom capabilities defined for agents:

Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39341041/how-to-specify-a-build-agent-in-vnext-build) for some more details.

Hope this helps.